# How to efficiently present results in the form of tables/graphs for this idea?

Tags: data-visualization

My idea is as follows.

The setting is that we have a population taking a survey after a social experiment. All of the test subjects are assumed to have interactions with each other in one way or another. There have been studies looking at how people herd towards the average of the whole population - however, I am looking to see whether they herd to groups that share similar attributes with them - for example, people that go to the same schools, people that work at the same workplaces, people with the same generation (gender Z, baby boomers, whatnot), people with the same gender, etc. I'm essentially looking for ways to efficient ways to show "a taste" to see if there's any herding behaviour within these groups of similar behaviours. I have the data with the people's details, including age, gender, countries of origin, schools, workplace, and their current locations.

I have done a little digging and here's what I found so far:

- Heat map: Cool idea, but the issue is that I have 300 different schools, and their detail level gets crazier if I get into workplaces or locations. Generation and (traditional) gender are fine since they won't exceed 10 dimensions. This problem also exists for methods like box plots.
- T-test: This idea won't work well because the t-test compares 2 samples. If I were to compare just people with groups and people without groups, I would feel somewhat icky. The whole purpose is to see if people are heard by smaller groups, so doing a t-test might defeat the purpose.
- Interactive map: This sadly won't work well since this is for a research paper and I can't create an interactive map yet.

I guess my biggest challenges include:

1. I don't know how to show people are herding to smaller groups when there are 300+ groups to show and I cannot fit them all into a page of table or graph.
2. I am unsure how to do summary statistics since most of the data is categorial - with schools and workplaces worrying me the most. I have done a dot distribution map and I certainly can do a small table counting how many people are in each generation. Maybe I can do the top 20 schools/workplaces and the number of people for each of those schools/workplaces?

I look forward to receiving any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look into multiple correspondence analysis (if you only have categorical variables) or factor analysis of mixed data (if you have a mix of categorical and numeric variables) in particular their representation under the form of a "graph of variables". But if you're not already familiar with that, you'll have some reading to do to interpret it correctly. In addition, MCA/FAMD is chiefly a descriptive method, not an inferential one (e.g. it's not a statistical test), so you'll have to be very careful if you want to generalize your conclusions.

Comment: Here is an example of a "graph of variables" for FAMD: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/115-famd-factor-analysis-of-mixed-data-in-r-essentials/#graph-of-variables (you'll have to scroll a bit to see it, it's the one titled "Variable groups - FAMD"). If you use that with your data, you won't see 300 items represented on the graph for your variable "school", but just 1 item called "school".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need some kind of dimensionality reduction technique of visualization. Have you tried if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding suits your needs?